# How to split an sentence by width using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here's is my problem.

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
>   tincidunt a purus et varius."

I want to split the above text by width say some 150px, space included & output array is something like.

> ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur" ," adipiscing elit. Nullam
>   tincidunt a purus" ,"et varius."]

I got the code to calculate width from somewhere, just want to split it & it doesn't have to fit into any div.Please help.

Hope I'm clear with the question.

This is the code I used to calculate width.  I'm not entirely sure it works for me.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl =    $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.html(text || this.val() || this.text()).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};
```

Comment: Post your code please!

Comment: This may not be you, but the most common reason people ask this is to do things the could already do with CSS. Make sure to look at `word-wrap`.

Comment: format the code properly please

Comment: @PaulDraper - I want to split the sentence and get the count.

Comment: Nevermind.. i used the good ol CSS.Thanks @PaulDraper.What was i thinking...